# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses' after upgrade

Tags: android, android-studio

recently i update android studio. And now I get an error that I don't really know how to solve.

i have search everywhere and i cant find a solution.

build-gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip
```

> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED

```
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedAppGlideModule found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.GenericTransitionOptions found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.Glide found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.GlideBuilder found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.GlideBuilder$1 found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.GlideContext found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.ListPreloader found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.ListPreloader$PreloadModelProvider found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.ListPreloader$PreloadSizeProvider found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.ListPreloader$PreloadTarget found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.ListPreloader$PreloadTargetQueue found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.MemoryCategory found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.ModelTypes found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.Priority found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.Registry found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.Registry$MissingComponentException found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoImageHeaderParserException found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoResultEncoderAvailableException found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoSourceEncoderAvailableException found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder$1 found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder$2 found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager$1 found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager$2 found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager$ClearTarget found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager$RequestManagerConnectivityListener found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.TransitionOptions found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.load.DecodeFormat found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.load.EncodeStrategy found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.load.Encoder found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$ImageType found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParserUtils found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.load.Key found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.load.MultiTransformation found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.load.Option found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.load.Option$1 found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.load.Option$CacheKeyUpdater found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.load.Options found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.load.ResourceDecoder found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.load.ResourceEncoder found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
     Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.load.Transformation found in modules glide-4.4.0 (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0) and glide-4.4.0-runtime (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0)
```

Comment: What has this to do with [tag:laravel]? I will change it accordingly

Comment: sorry my misstake.